# Using arguments in addConstraint() for validation

Tags: 8, nodes

I implemented `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter()` to add validation to fields of a node type. I got `$bundle` as an argument in the hook and I need to pass it in `$options` argument like below:

```
$fields['field_tags']->addConstraint('NodeValidate', $bundle);
```

How can I access this argument in `NodeValidateConstraintValidator`? Am I passing the argument correctly?

`$options` provided in `addConstraint` can be accessed in the constructor using `parent::__construct($options)` in `__construct()` function build the options.

`hook_entity_base_field_info_alter()` doesn't contain a `$bundle` argument, as it is defined as `function hook_entity_base_field_info_alter(&$fields, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type)`. How can I validate the base field for a particular node type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Options needs to be an array I think. You can access it on the constraint object in your validator, see `ListStringItem::propertyDefinitions()` and LengthValidator, which then uses it as $constraint->max.
2. Base fields are exactly that. Base fields. There is no bundle, they are the same for all bundles of an entity type (they can be overriden per-bundle, but then they become accessible in the bundle hook).
3. You shouldn't ask two different questions together :)

Comment: Sorry for asking two questions on a single post. I'm a bit lazy :( . Can you please explain the 2nd point that states overriding per-bundle. If i need to validate title field of a particular node type which hook should I use?

Comment: I looked at `propertyDefinitions()` and `LengthValidator` and tried to do the same but it just throwed me an error. I think there is something to do with `constructor` in `Length.php` . But I can't get it

Answer (score 0):

To pass arguments in `addConstraint()` something like:

```
$fields['field_tags]->addConstraint('NodeValidate', array('bundle' => 'article));
```

You should create a constructor in `NodeValidateConstraint.php` and calling the `parent constructor` like below:

**You should need to declare a property name same as the name of the key in the options you passed. In this case it is `bundle`.**

```
class NodeValidateConstraint extends Constraint {
  public $bundle;
  public function __construct($options = null)
  {
      parent::__construct($options);
  }
}
```

Now you could access the $options in `NodeValidateConstraintValidator.php` as

```
$bundle_name = $constraint->bundle;
```

Thanks berdir for guiding me in this and continuously responding to my queries in drupal 8:)